# Should I add RecyclerView dependency to gradle if it works without it?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, gradle, android-recyclerview

I have some android projects, where I use often use RecyclerView(if it matters, it's the widget with androidx prefix) without adding any dependencies. But when I look gradle-files of another projects(even which developed by Google), I see this dependency:

```
implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:$recycler_view_version"
```

So, I have questions.

1. Should I add it to my gradle if I don't have any problems with RecyclerView?
2. Maybe is there another dependency, which includes RecyclerView as well?

Comment: why don't you give it a shot? just delete em and see the result for yourself??

Comment: @Sekiro what should I delete? Every dependency in my gradle? If it's the only choice, maybe later, but I asked, because I want more information. New Android Studio project supports RecyclerView completely(or I don't know about some specific usages).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you have created your project in androix.

Material dependency :-

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
```

Basically material dependency contains all the widgets implementation. So you can access those widgets directly after injecting this dependency.

It may be possible that you have added material dependency in your gradle. so after injection of material dependency no need to inject separate recyclerview's dependency.

Comment: For real, I have that dependency, but for now it's standard dependency, I didn't add it. Thank you!